# App Engine points to wrong project locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a Google App Engine Project with Python 3 and Firestore Native.

It's already **running fine in the cloud**, but when I run the app **locally**, I get:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 
The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project *some-other-project-of-mine*
```

It is complaining that another/completely unrelated project does not have firestore access (which is true).

I don't understand why the permissions of this other project is being checked. I have isolated enviroment with pyenv, python interpreter and dependencies live there. I have also set

```
gcloud config set project my-firestore-project
```

but still somewhere there is a link to this other project. Where could that be and how can I break that connection?

For reference, this is [the article / code samples](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-developing-an-app-engine-service-with-python-and-cloud-firestore-1640f92e14f4) I was following.

Comment: is it possible the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` file you provided belongs to a service account that is tied to the other project

Comment: @Alex thanks, that was it! if you submit your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Best, Hoff

Comment: Submitted it as an answer. Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the instructions you linked (https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-developing-an-app-engine-service-with-python-and-cloud-firestore-1640f92e14f4):

> Next, you need to set up Google Application Default Credentials. This enables you to locally test the service before deploying it to GAE. Local testing does create some extra work, but in the long run it saves a lot of time and effort. Download a service account JSON file for your Firebase project, and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to it.
>
> `(env) $ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/creds.json`

Is it possible the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` file you provided belongs to a service account that is tied to the other project?